# MySQL separate data to two new columns

Tags: mysql, sql

One column contains a comma between data and I want to show these different data in two new columns to my question. Examples of data, column CarAndYear: [Volvo, 1995]
I want the 'Volvo' to be displayed in the column Cars and the year '1995 'in the column Year. I would be very grateful for help with this MySQL issue.

Comment: Is it always the same structure of the data?

Comment: Following post would help you about this. Also there are several hundred similar question here on SO. [http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you always have leading and trailing brackets:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(CarAndYear, 2, INSTR(CarAndYear, ',') - 2)) Cars, 
       TRIM(SUBSTR(CarAndYear, INSTR(CarAndYear, ',') + 1, LENGTH(CarAndYear) - INSTR(CarAndYear, ',') -1)) `Year`
FROM (SELECT '[Volvo, 1995]' CarAndYear) n
```

Output

```
+-------+-------+
| Cars  | Year  |
+-------+-------+
| Volvo |  1995 |
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM `columnname`),',',1) as CARS,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM `columnname`),',',-1) as Year 
FROM `tablename`;
```

[SUBSTRING_INDEX in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

[TRIM in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

Comment: It becomes more difficult for me to separate the following data into three columns: 

VOLVO, 1995:7

Cars
Year
Info

Data separated between both comma and colon. Ideas?

Comment: 3 columns are fine, for four and more columns, I advise you to select out the data first, then use other language like python, perl to manipulate these strings. @Nyfiken